# How to execute asynchronously three separate queries in one method using ADO.NET ExecuteScalarAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ado.net, task

So I'm trying to turn my synchronous method to asnych. The set up is - I have a method that check if an user uses any of the company products. I need different query for each product so I decided to try and give a shot to the asnych programming since I've never tried using `Task` and `await` before even though, maybe this is not the perfect situation to do it. But however now I've changed my method to this:

```
    private static async Task<bool> isUsingProducts(int clientId)
    {
      bool hasProduct = false;

        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand firstProduct = new SqlCommand(firstQuery, connection1);

            firstProduct.CommandTimeout = 300;
            firstProduct.Open();
            Task numberOfUsedProducts1 = firstProduct.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            //int numberOfUsedProducts = (int)firstProduct.ExecuteScalar();
            //if (0 < numberOfUsedProducts)
            //{
            //    hasProduct = true;
            //}
        }
        using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand secondProduct= new SqlCommand(secondQuery, connection2);
            secondProduct.CommandTimeout = 300;
            connection2.Open();
            Task numberOfUsedProducts2 = secondProduct.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            //int numberOfUsedProducts = (int)secondProduct.ExecuteScalar();
            //if (0 < numberOfUsedProducts)
            //{
            //    hasProduct = true;
            //}
        }

        return hasProduct;
    }
```

Basically this is some mix from what I've tried and what has left from the previous method which was synchronous. In this case I only care if the user is using ANY of the products or not so I was checking after the end of each query. However sometimes I'm gonna need the actual count so at the end I want to be able to execute the queries in asnych mode and later decied how exactly i'm gonna deal with the results.

Right now this:

```
 Task numberOfUsedProducts2 = secondProduct.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

is not giving me an error, but I don't know how to proceed. What I don't know how to do is how to add the logic for checking the result of each query (the queries are synch so how shall I know that there's a result already) and how to convert those result to the actual type (`int`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteScalarAsync` return a `Task<object>`. You can use a `cast` on the return type in combination with `await`:

```
int numberOfUsedProducts1 = (int) await firstProduct.ExecuteScalarAsync()

if (numberOfUsedProducts > 0)
{
     hasProduct = true;
}
```

Same goes for the second method as well.

> Right now this:

```
 Task numberOfUsedProducts2 = secondProduct.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

> is not giving me an error

That's because a `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`, so you may use it as the more abstracted base class, but then you lose the `Result` property containing the returned `T`

Comment: I ahve problems - the process never ends. But I have to go now. Gonna get in later.

Comment: For some reasons I have problems with this code on my real project but I test it right now and it works.Thanks